# javascript window.print after loading multiple google map through php loop

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am successful to display multiple maps through a php loop. But at the end I am calling window.print. My problem is that the window.print is getting triggered before the map loads and blank space is shown on the print page.

Here is my example code:

```html
{loop starts}

<div latitude="<?php echo $row['lat'];?>" longitude="<?php echo $row['lng'];?>" zoom="<?php echo $row['map_zoom_level'];?>"  class="map_canvas"></div>

{loop ends}
```

Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.map_canvas').each(function(index, Element) {
      var lat = $(Element).attr('latitude');
      var lng = $(Element).attr('longitude');

      var latlng = lat+','+lng;
      var zoomlevel = parseInt($(Element).attr('zoom'));

      var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)

      $(Element).gmap({'zoom': zoomlevel}).bind('init', function(ev, map) {
         $(Element).gmap('get','map').setOptions({'center':origin});
         $(Element).gmap('addMarker', {'position': latlng}).click();
      });
   });
   window.print();
});
```

Can anyone help me fix this.

Comment: move your window.print(); outside the (document).ready(function(){} and into a separate function.

Comment: call `window.print()` when the `tilesloaded`-event of the map fires